# How to center a div without manually defining its width

Tags: html, css

I have some bullet points inside a div, and I want the bullet points to be aligned vertically. I also want the div to be in the center of the page. However, I do not want to have to manually define the width of the div, because I do not know in advance the size of each bullet point. How can I center the div without pre-defining the width?

The code I have so far is:

```
<div style='text-align:left;width:100px;margin:0 auto'>
    <ul>
        <li>Alpha</li>
        <li>Beta</li>
        <li>Gamma</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And a JSFiddle can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/7R2qJ/

(Note that in this code, the div width is manually defined, which I want to avoid).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` to the parent, and `text-align: left` to the div. I find this helps in some versions of IE. Then add `display: inline-block` to the div too.

http://jsfiddle.net/7R2qJ/8/

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Alpha</li>
        <li>Beta</li>
        <li>Gamma</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

-

```
body
{
    text-align: center;
}

div
{
    background: yellow;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This does not give the div a width; it just spans the entire width of its parent: http://jsfiddle.net/7R2qJ/6/

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `display: table;` combined with `margin: 0 auto;`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7R2qJ/2/)

Answer (score 0):

use the `display:inline-block;` property to wrap the width of the div to its content

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6N4yN/#fork)**

css

```
body
{
    text-align: center;
}

.list
{
    background: yellow;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

markup

```
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>Alpha</li>
        <li>Beta</li>
        <li>Gamma</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```